# Сервер возвращает ошибку когда отправляю запрос с русскими буквами

Tags: php, xml

Собственно есть сервер, который принимает запросы в xml, и возвращает ответы тоже в xml. Мне нужно с ним сделать обмен данными из opencart'а. Всё работает если отправлять запросы без русских букв. С русскими буквами сервер возвращает следующий ответ: **XML parsing failed ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00007: unexpected end-of-file encountered**. Пытался в xml, в атрибуты прописывать кодировку UTF-8. Пытался отправлять в заголовках сведения о кодировке. Ничего не выходит. Техподдержка сервера с которым я связываюсь ничего толком не может сказать по этой ошибке. Сказали что сервер тоже работает с UTF-8.
И ещё что странно, я пробовал у себя на локальном openserver'е отправлять с русскими буквами, всё работало. А получается на хостинге не работает.

Comment: Покажите примеры запросов. Чтобы сохранить кодировку, упакуйте их в архив и положите на файлообменник.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была на хостинге, конкретнее в настройке `mbstring.func_overload`. Хостинг был заточен под 1С битрикс.